# Unable to make html file responsive on mobile device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 to build a website. When using google chrome's device toggle toolbar, my website's homepage isn't able to display the screen properly on any of the handheld devices; I need to scroll to see all three posters. But If I click onto movie1, all the content is displayed perfectly(no scrolling needed). Both the files use the same css file.

I've made sure to include this code in both the html files:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and this into the css file:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px){
}
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
     
}
```

This is the code for the head of the homepage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=0">

        <link rel="icon" href="movie-symbol-of-video-camera_icon-icons.com_72981.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>indextest</title>
        <style>
            
        </style>
    </head>
```

This is the code for the head of the movie1 html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="../static/images/movie-symbol-of-video-camera_icon-icons.com_72981.png">-->
    <link rel="icon" href="movie-symbol-of-video-camera_icon-icons.com_72981.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

Not sure why one page is working and the other isn't. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Fig below: Content not displayed properly; need to scroll to see rest of the page
[image]

Fig below: content fits perfectly; no scrolling needed
[image]

Comment: your media queries are empty. Is that intentional?

Comment: Could you show us the relevant CSS - also describe why there is nothing in the media queries - are you trying to style differently for smaller viewports?

Answer (score 0):

### I dont know what you want, exactly. But, if you are using bootstrap 4 then use bootstrap 4 classes for responsive screen and use CSS media query for another view using its class or make your own class to implement view acc. to you.

> I have added some example by using your screen which is responsive for
> all screen's using bootstrap 4 grid classes and other classes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Home Page</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="www.google.com">
    </div>
    <div class="col-11">
        <p>A movie poster for movie 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col badge badge-success my-2 mx-2">Netflix</div>
    <div class="col badge badge-success my-2 mx-2">Amazon Prime</div>
    <div class="col badge badge-success my-2 mx-2">Hulu</div>
    <div class="col badge badge-success my-2 mx-2">Disney+</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Home Page</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="www.google.com">
    </div>
    <div class="col-11">
        <p>A movie poster for movie 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col badge badge-success my-2 mx-2">Netflix</div>
    <div class="col badge badge-success my-2 mx-2">Amazon Prime</div>
    <div class="col badge badge-success my-2 mx-2">Hulu</div>
    <div class="col badge badge-success my-2 mx-2">Disney+</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```